# IfIf $a_n<b_n \forall$ $n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n<\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $a_n<b_n \forall$ $n$, does that imply that  $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n<\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$?

My answer: No, if I take $a_n=\frac{1}{1+n^2}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$,
$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=0$

Is this correct?

Comment: yes you are correct!

Comment: @PJK Thank you! that means I secured one question in my last exam :D

Comment: Not too sure about that if you actually wrote $x\rightarrow\infty$ instead of $n\rightarrow\infty$ :)

Comment: You can go easier with $a_n = 0$ and $b_n  = 1/n$, or more generally, take any bounded, strictly decreasing sequence for $b_n$ and let $a_n = \lim b_k$ for all $n$.